# Error in installing the 'Firebase/Crashlytics' pod in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

> I am installing the pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' into my Xcode project.
>   the project configuration is: 
>   XCode: 10.3 
>   Swift Version: 4.2 
>   Pod Version: 1.8.0.beta.2

**Error after pod install:**

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.4.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Auth was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.4.0)

    Firebase/Crashlytics was resolved to 6.15.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.15.0)

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `Projects` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Other pods in my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

pod 'SwifterSwift'
pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Nuke'
pod 'FlagPhoneNumber'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'SDDownloadManager'
pod 'Cosmos', '~> 18.0'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.2.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '= 4.0'
pod 'AppImageViewer'
pod 'MDGroupAvatarView'
pod 'OpalImagePicker'
pod 'KMPlaceholderTextView', '~> 1.4.0'
pod 'CropViewController'
pod 'GrowingTextView', '0.6.1'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
end
```

Comment: I would suggest remove `Firebase/Core`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is issue was coming due to diff version of pods because the old
> firebase pods were not updated and the default new pod are installed
> with a higher version.

**To install new pod and update the old pods**

1. We have to update the cocoa-pods
2. Update specific pods so that other pods won't be disturbed

[image]

Answer (score 9):

change

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

to

```
pod 'Firebase/CoreOnly'
```

**Edited:**

For my case, I've specified pod version in Podfile, so I have to change this line in my Podfile.

Comment: While this may answer the question, a good post will include more details on what was changed and why.

Comment: I've read the error that @Suhas has posted. 

He wants to install `Firebase/Crashlytics` which depends on `Firebase/CoreOnly`, so he needs to change to use 'Firebase/CoreOnly' instead of 'Firebase/Core'. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just a few steps**

Step 1: `Firebase/CoreOnly` pod update

```
pod update 'Firebase/CoreOnly'
```

Step 2: pod install

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an extra line with old version

```
pod 'Firebase', '6.13.0'
```

Just removing the line solved the issue. Or you can change the version to the latest version.